# Facebook SDK Login Dialog

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-authentication

I've got the problem while working with facebook iOS sdk. 
I integrated it with my app and everything works fine except one thing.

In iOS 11 there is login dialog:
**AppName wants to use "facebook.com" to sign in**

So, if I lock the device when this dialog is on the screen and then unlock it, dialog disappears and I could not login until restart the app because completion of method

```
- (void)logInWithReadPermissions:(NSArray *)permissions
              fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromViewController
                         handler:(FBSDKLoginManagerRequestTokenHandler)handler;
```

will never be called.

I've walked through the method calls in FacebookSDK and found, that internal `_state` of `FBSDKLoginManager` is in `FBSDKLoginManagerStateStart` state and do not drop down if the device is blocked. So, manager will not allow us to go further.

Is there any way to drop down this state?

Answer (score 0):

this issue has been reported to Facebook (https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/955483087941463/) and should be fixed with Version 4.30.0 of the iOS SDK.

Comment: Still getting under 4.31.1